# Easiest way to store little information

Tags: javascript, sql, database

I am quite new to coding so apologies if I'm asking an obvious question. I have managed to create a little web app in html/JavaScript that takes user input and transforms it and dumps it into a variable that I am interested in. All in all, all the information that I want to extract is in the form of an array comprising of 20 integers in the JavaScript code.

What I want to do now is find how to store that information so when somebody fills out the inputs and submits the form - I can have access to it. I have looked around the web and the common suggestion seems to be SQL database. I was just wondering if there is a simpler way of going about it, especially considering the tiny amount of information I need to store?

Comment: Hi Floran, Does security matter for you?

Comment: You could use a small php script to store the data in a file on your server (could be csv, json or something similar). Also you could protect the file using a htaccess configuration if you are using an apache webserver

Comment: No, the data is not sensitive in any way, it's a mock-game scenario for research. The output is just numbers.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: http://www.kodecrash.com/javascript/read-write-json-file-using-php/

Comment: What kind of server do you have?

Comment: Personally I like firebase for this kind of thing.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you just want to store the data on the website itself for each individual client, localStorage is the way to go. In other words, if you want to just store a bit of data for later, localStorage allows you to store data that is accessible the next time the user loads the page. This data can't be shared with other users, but if your app doesn't need too much security, or data sharing between users, localStorage is the way to go. However, the user can control what's in localStorage, so you need to make sure that you don't store anything sensitive there. In addition, you won't be able to see the data actually stored in localStorage on your website as the developer. All your handling has to be done on the client side. Every browser supports it, and it's really simple to use.
First off, you can set a value in localStorage like this:

```
localStorage.foo = "bar";
```

Then, you can get a value from localStorage like this:

```
localStorage.foo; //Returns "bar"
```

The only problem is, localStorage values can only be stored as strings.
So, in order to store an array (like you wanted to), you can do:

```
localStorage.arr = JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]);
```

This turns the array into a string.
Then, to get the array from localStorage:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.arr)
```

That's pretty much all you need to know for what you are describing. 
If you want the full story on localStorage, visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
I hope this answer helped.

Comment: I think he means on the server, because he states "I can have access to it"

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought that he was only using HTML and JS.